# error _.K {lat: ƒ, lng: ƒ} or setpostion of latlong not number

Tags: ionic-framework

the lat and long is changable as realtime tracking from data , i use get http from url, and i use interval observoable to reload but i fail to the marker .

```
droneMarker(data) {
      var Newlat = data.iss_position.latitude;
      var nlat = +Newlat;
      var Newlng = data.iss_position.longitude;
      var nlng = +Newlng;
    var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng([nlat, nlng]);
      console.log(latlong);
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlong,
        map: this.map,
        icon: {
          url: 'assets/markers/drone_location.png',
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(80, 80),
        }});}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
droneMarker(data) {
    var Newlat = data.iss_position.latitude;
    var Newlng = data.iss_position.longitude;
    var latlong = {
      Newlat,
      Newlng
    };

    console.log(latlong);
    const marker = new SlidingMarker({
      position: {
        lat: parseFloat(data.iss_position.latitude),
        lng: parseFloat(data.iss_position.longitude)
      },
      map: this.map,
      icon: {
        url: 'assets/markers/drone_location.png',
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(80, 80),
      }
    });
```